# Transfer ownership with Java client

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am using the Java client of the Google Drive SDK.

Application goal: transfer ownership of all files to parent owner. By this, I mean there are a number of accounts with large storage amounts eg. StorageAcct1, StorageAcct2, etc. If a user moves their files into that account, they still retain ownership and incur a storage penalty. What I would like my application to do is run in the background and transfer ownership to the storage accounts.

I have created a drive service object as StorageAcct1 and authenticated to the domain. I can authenticate as StorageAcct1 and list all files as well as add/remove writer and viewer permissions. However, I cannot transfer ownership. By this, if AppsUser1 owns Document1, StorageAcct1 cannot obtain ownership even if the account is set as a Super Admin or Drive Admin.

I have noticed if I create a new service object as the owner I can then transfer the ownership. (Create service account as AppsUser1@domain.com to transfer ownership of Document1 to StorageAcct1).

Since the permissions API calls do not return the owner's emails and just names, I cannot programatically go through the list of files and transfer ownership. I would prefer to not have to add in a database to lookup a name vs email and tie that in with the Provisioning API.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to transfer ownership if the new owner is on a different domain than the existing one, otherwise you should be able to modify the owner.

If you have a list of users who are on different domains and would like to know the user's domain to match it with his domain's service account, make a request to userinfo to retrieve his/her domain:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
{
  "email": "email@domain.com",
  "hd": "domain.com"
}
```

You will still need to match a domain to a service account though.